# Checkbox is hidden when in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

For some reason the checkboxes will not appear, however when I move them out of the form they show up. Also, they appear in IE but not Chrome.

```
    <p><span style="color: #474747; font-size: 1.35em; font-weight: 800; letter-spacing: 0.04em; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 1.85em;">Delete Images </span>
     <?php
    // SCAN DIRECTORIES
    $dirG    = '../products/'.$trailertoedit.'/gallery/';
    $dirGallerys = scandir($dirG);

    foreach ($dirGallerys as $dirGallery) {
        if ($dirGallery === '.' or $dirGallery === '..' or $dirGallery === 'index.php') continue;

        if (is_dir($dirG)) {
            echo '<br>checkbox<input type="checkbox">Delete '.$dirGallery.' -> ';
            echo '<a href="'.$dirG.$dirGallery.'" data-lightbox="trailer"><img src="'.$dirG.$dirGallery.'" height="100px"></a>';
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You are not using valid html. input tags are self closing and require `/>` at the end

Comment: I've done it both ways, it doesn't work either way.

Comment: Is it not showing up because `$dirG` is not a directory?

Comment: css rule hiding them? use a DOM inspector to see what rules are in effect on them.

Comment: I've tried that both ways too, all I need it to do right now is just be visible.

Comment: $dirG is a directory

The checkbox appears in the source code but not on screen

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp according to w3schools, the closing tag `/>` isn't required in html.

Comment: Is it visible in an empty document with just basic tags? It's visible on my pages, when I copied and pasted `<input type="checkbox">`. Have you tried other browsers? Are other checkboxes visible?

Comment: I have the same tag visible on this page however within the form it is not visible...anywhere.

Upon further investigation I realized that all boxes appear in IE but not Chrome.